# Fancyhdr - How to add a footer line outside of the footer area?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am a beginner in LaTeX, tentatively using it for industrial documents. I am trying to mimic a company form. I do not understand why in the MWE, the content of the minipage, that I would like to see underneath the header rule, on the right side, is visible in the area reserved for the header. Also, I would like the the last line "Written by:  Writer's name \hfill   Approved by: Approver's name" to appear at the bottom of page, immediately above the footer line, regardless of the contents of the first page. I could not find a way to do this or to understand the behavior of the minipage. Perhaps there is also a better way to show the title underneath the right half of the header rule... Added note: 
The "written by..." statements should appear  on the font page only. As a matter of fact there would be some logic in adding this to the contents of the footer of the front page, with additional arguments in the "Document parameters" list (these parameters are located in my original code on a separate file), such as \WriterName, \ReleaseDate, \ApproverName, etc, but it should appear above the footer rule line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[top=10mm, bottom=40mm, left=19mm, right=19mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros,textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\usepackage[ french,english,]{babel} 

\def\LegalStatement{ %
\footnotesize\noindent\raggedright
\parbox[t]{.45\linewidth}{The Great Company Inc \\ MAILBOX 58670 PARIS TEXAS USA} \parbox[t]{.45\linewidth}{\copyright \thinspace \the\year~Company name The Great Company Corporation \\All international rights reserved\\ (\selectlanguage{french}Tous droits réservés)}
\medskip
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{Ce document est sujet à modifications. Contacter Company Inc pour identifier la dernière révision et en obtenir une copie. Personnel Company name Inc: consultez la base de données "database centrale".
\selectlanguage{english}This document, managed by Company name Inc, is archived in the Central database. 
A printout cannot be considered as a controlled document}
}

%ARGUMENTS FOR DOCUMENT
\def\DocumentNumber {XXXXXX}
\def\HeaderLogo {Logo.pdf}
\def\DocumentName{DOCUMENT NAME} 
\def\DocumentType{Educational \\Specification}
\def\RevisionNumber{A }
\selectlanguage{english} %main language of document.
%END ARGUMENTS FOR DOCUMENT

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%HEADERS AND FOOTERS EXCEPT FRONT PAGE
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Redefining in next lines  headers and their style.
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\bfseries\large{\DocumentType}}
\rhead{\textcolor{blue}{\large\bfseries{\DocumentNumber} \\ \footnotesize{\today}  \\ Rev \quad  \RevisionNumber}}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{\HeaderLogo}}
\lfoot{\bfseries\large{Rev \RevisionNumber}}
\rfoot{\bfseries{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\headheight}{2 cm} %  [thickness header line]-
\renewcommand{\headwidth}{\linewidth}%  [horizontal length header line]
\renewcommand{\headsep}{0.5 cm}%   [distance header-main text]
\renewcommand{\footskip}{2 cm} %  [distance footer-main text]
} %
% END HEADERS AND FOOTERS EXCEPT FRONT PAGE

%HEADER AND FOOTER FOR FRONT PAGE 
\fancypagestyle{FrontPage}{% Redefining in next lines  headers and their style.
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\bfseries\large{\DocumentType}}
\rhead{\textcolor{blue}{\large\bfseries{\DocumentNumber} \\ \footnotesize{\today}  \\ Rev \quad  \RevisionNumber - PRELIMINARY }}
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm, width=2.5cm]{\HeaderLogo}}
\cfoot{\LegalStatement}
\rfoot{\bfseries{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\headsep}{0 cm}%   [distance header-main text] --
\renewcommand{\footskip}{1 cm} %  [distance footer-main text]--
} %
 %--END HEADERS FOOTER FRONT PAGE

%---BEGIN FRONT PAGE
\begin{document}  

\thispagestyle{FrontPage}
\raggedleft
\vspace{4cm}
\begin{minipage}[c][][c]{.5\textwidth}
\centering\Large{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\DocumentName}}} \\
\normalsize\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}
\end{minipage}

\raggedright
\section{Scope}
\lipsum[2-4]

Written by:  Writer's name \hfill   Approved by: Approver's name
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the "Written by, Approved by" line appear on *every* page?

Comment: The answer is "yes". I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Your answer in the comment says "yes" to *every page*, but your edit to the question says "on the front page only".

Comment: Sorry I meant the first page only.

Comment: @egrep. I have had the idea to start the footer with the "written by" etc note, add a rule underneath, and make the thickness of the normal header rule to zero. Would an approach like this make sense?

Comment: Regarding the header, note that your `FrontPage` style is not setting `\headheight` and your definition of `FrontPage` includes lots of unwanted spaces --- try ensuring that each line in that definition ends with a comment `%` immediately after the last `}` on the line (no spaces before). Also, though probably not neccesary if you can fix the header properly, your `\vspace` before the minipage is being ignored. Using the starred form, `\vspace*` works.

Comment: The approach you suggested for the footer is also recommended, as the position of the 'normal' footer rule is before the footer (and I believe is not adjustable or at least not worth attempting to adjust), so you do not want that rule to appear, while semantically, you do want a rule to appear as the last item in the footer itself.

Answer (score 1):

If this were a 1-page document a simple `\vfill` would suffice before the "written by" line to ensure it ends up in the bottom. Since it may have several pages, one approach is to define a `\customfooter` command that includes that line and replaces the original `\footrule`. Also, `\footrulewidth` must be set to zero so you don't end up with two rules.

Regarding the minipage, its behavior is normal, the problem is that it starts with reference to a line of text - and the first line of text is right after the heading. Since `\headheight` was too small it was starting at that position. `\headheight` needs to be larger to accomodate all the content that's going in the heading. Setting it to the suggested value at compilation worked when I tried your example (with an additional `\vspace{0.5cm}` *inside* the minipage.

The following worked in my setup:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[top=10mm, bottom=40mm, left=19mm, right=19mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros,textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\usepackage[ french,english,]{babel} 

\def\LegalStatement{ %
\footnotesize\noindent\raggedright
\parbox[t]{.45\linewidth}{The Great Company Inc \\ MAILBOX 58670 PARIS TEXAS USA} \parbox[t]{.45\linewidth}{\copyright \thinspace \the\year~Company name The Great Company Corporation \\All international rights reserved\\ (\selectlanguage{french}Tous droits réservés)}
\medskip
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{Ce document est sujet à modifications. Contacter Company Inc pour identifier la dernière révision et en obtenir une copie. Personnel Company name Inc: consultez la base de données "database centrale".
\selectlanguage{english}This document, managed by Company name Inc, is archived in the Central database. 
A printout cannot be considered as a controlled document}
}

%ARGUMENTS FOR DOCUMENT
\def\DocumentNumber {XXXXXX}
\def\HeaderLogo {Logo.pdf}
\def\DocumentName{DOCUMENT NAME} 
\def\DocumentType{Educational \\Specification}
\def\RevisionNumber{A }
\selectlanguage{english} %main language of document.
%END ARGUMENTS FOR DOCUMENT

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%HEADERS AND FOOTERS EXCEPT FRONT PAGE
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Redefining in next lines  headers and their style.
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\bfseries\large{\DocumentType}}
\rhead{\textcolor{blue}{\large\bfseries{\DocumentNumber} \\ \footnotesize{\today}  \\ Rev \quad  \RevisionNumber}}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{\HeaderLogo}}
\lfoot{\bfseries\large{Rev \RevisionNumber}}
\rfoot{\bfseries{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\headheight}{2 cm} %  [thickness header line]-
\renewcommand{\headwidth}{\linewidth}%  [horizontal length header line]
\renewcommand{\headsep}{0.5 cm}%   [distance header-main text]
\renewcommand{\footskip}{2 cm} %  [distance footer-main text]
} %
% END HEADERS AND FOOTERS EXCEPT FRONT PAGE

%HEADER AND FOOTER FOR FRONT PAGE 
\fancypagestyle{FrontPage}{% Redefining in next lines  headers and their style.
\fancyhf{}%
\chead{\bfseries\large{\DocumentType}}%
\rhead{\textcolor{blue}{\large\bfseries{\DocumentNumber} \\ \footnotesize{\today}  \\ Rev \quad  \RevisionNumber - PRELIMINARY }}%
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm, width=2.5cm]{\HeaderLogo}}%
\cfoot{\customfooter}%
\rfoot{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\headheight}{47 pt}%
\renewcommand{\headsep}{0 cm}%   [distance header-main text] --
\renewcommand{\footskip}{1 cm}%  [distance footer-main text]--
} %
 %--END HEADERS FOOTER FRONT PAGE

\newcommand{\customfooter}{
\vspace{-1.2cm}
Written by:  Writer's name \hfill   Approved by: Approver's name
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt} 
\bfseries{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}\hfill\LegalStatement\hfill}


%---BEGIN FRONT PAGE
\begin{document}  

\thispagestyle{FrontPage}
\raggedleft
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\vspace{.5cm}
\centering\Large{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\DocumentName}}}
\rule{.5\textwidth}{2pt}
\end{minipage}

\raggedright
\section{Scope}

\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```